# Is Collection of Big O's a Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the object
$$ M = \{ \mathcal{O}(f(x)) \mid f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \}$$
a set? Or perhaps take $\Omega(f(x))$ instead?

Comment: Yes - it's a set of sets of functions. What could go wrong?

Comment: Ohhhhhh... No objections. I guess I was somehow confused by whatever reason.. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is a set

Comment: Out of interest, where did you encounter this set $M$?

Comment: I was talking to a friend about "non-trivial" total order relations and I had the idea to take "complexity of a function" as an order relation (so $x^2 = 42x^2$ but $x^2 < e^x$) - it was just an idea that came to my mind but at least seemed interesting/cool to me.

Comment: That makes sense and it does indeed capture how we think about big $O$ notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a set (at least according to [the standard axioms of set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory)).

What you've described is a set of sets of functions. Sets of sets of sets of ... may feel weird at first, but are perfectly legal objects, and the axioms of ZFC in fact prove that they exist.

---

In fact, in ZFC *everything* is a set! For example, here is one way the real numbers can be implemented inside ZFC (in the same way that an algorithm can be implemented in a language via a specific program):

- A real number is a set of rational numbers (the left Dedekind cut).
- A rational number is a set of ordered pairs of integers (= the set of representations of that rational).
- An integer is a pair of the form $(m, i)$ where $m$ is a natural number and $i=0$ ("negative") or $1$ ("positive") - with the rule that we don't allow $(0, 0)$ (we don't distinguish between $+0$ and $-0$).
- Natural numbers - **this part is standard in set theory** - are [finite ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number): $0$ is $\emptyset$ and $n+1$ is $n\cup\{n\}$.

And **all of this** is ultimately built just out of the emptyset, via complicated "sets-of-sets-of..." business! *(Note that for now I'm ignoring the question of whether e.g. $0$ **actually is** $\emptyset$ - I'm thinking of ZFC as simply giving a specific way to implement mathematics that I already know about "somehow else.")*

Comment: Yes, thanks! For whatever reason, I was confused and thought that functions could make things weird (just like there is no set of all sets in ZFC) but you reminded me - of course, there is a set of functions!

Comment: @Kezer The crucial thing is that there is a set of functions *from one specific set to another* - similarly, there is a set of all sets *which are contained in one specific set* (namely, the powerset). These constructions always work "locally," it's when we try to really get **everything** into a single set that we run into problems.

Comment: Ah yeah, a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined set-theoretically is just some element of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ in our case, so we'll dealing with a set of some subset of some subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ which clearly exists. 

I guess when the object first came up in our conversation, it was all very vague and we only talked about functions in general, so that's where the confusion came of.

It's all clear now, thank you!

Comment: @Kezer No, a function defined set-theoretically is a *subset* of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ - namely, we identify $f$ with its graph $\{(a, b)\in\mathbb{R}^2: f(a)=b\}$. But the broader point is correct.

Comment: Uh yeah. Sorry. That's what I meant. Hence the "subset" in the second part of that sentence.